# How to extract specific set of date from a date column of an CSV file using Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to access some specific values from the date column from my CSV file and save to another.

here 'f' is the data frame of my csv file, "now" is the current date, "f['Date']"is the column which has to be manupilated, 
LOGIC:

if current day is monday then im subtracting 2 days from the current date and then storing it in "day" and accessing the dates in f['Date'] column which are equivalent to the "day" date.
else we re subtracting only 1 day and doing the same.

```py
now = date.today()
curr_day= now.strftime("%A")
now = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

f['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(f['Date'])
# f['Date'] = f['Date'].apply( lambda x : x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
f['Date'] = f['Date'].astype(str)
if curr_day == 'Monday':

    day = datetime.datetime.strptime(now,"%Y-%m-%d").date() - timedelta(days=2)
    day= day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    f['Date']=f.loc[f['Date']==day]

else:

    day = datetime.datetime.strptime(now,"%Y-%m-%d").date() - timedelta(days=1)
    day= day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    f['Date']=f.loc[f['Date']==day]
```

I have a date lets say: DATE1 
and I need to access only those values in the date column which are equivalent to the DATE1 and the save to the new CSV file.

```
Date
01-Apr-19
02-Apr-19
03-Apr-19
14-Apr-19
18-Apr-19
14-Apr-19
14-Apr-19
14-Apr-19
01-Apr-19
10-Apr-19
01-Apr-19
01-Apr-19
```

Assume DATE1=14-04-2019

Then the updated CSV will look like

```
Date
14-Apr-19
14-Apr-19
14-Apr-19
14-Apr-19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the date format you have given and adding my response. I am attaching the code for your solution!

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'],format='%d-%b-%y')
data['date'] = data['date'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
now = datetime.now()
day = now.strftime("%A")
if day=='Monday':
    days_to_subtract = 2
    date_filter = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=days_to_subtract)
    new_data = data.loc[data['date']==(date_filter).date()]
    new_data.drop('date',1,inplace = True)
    new_data.reset_index(drop=True,inplace = True)
else:
    days_to_subtract = 1    
    date_filter = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=days_to_subtract)
    new_data = data.loc[data['date']==(date_filter).date()]
    new_data.drop('date',1,inplace = True)
    new_data.reset_index(drop=True,inplace = True)
```